# Modal Stage isResizable

Tags: tornadofx

For TornadoFX 1.7.0, is there anyway to make a fragment not resizable when it is opened as a Modal?

I would like to make the modal not resizable so you cannot maximize or change the size of the dialog in any way.

There is no isResizable option in the open modal option

```
        fragment.openModal(isResizable = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The current best way to do this is from the `onDock` callback of the UIComponent:

```
override fun onDock() {
    modalStage?.isResizable = false 
}
```

The reason for this is that if you add `block = true`, your callback wouldn't complete until the modal dialog closes, so it would never kick in.

I just committed an optional `resizable` parameter to `openModal()` and `openWindow()` so that you can do this more conveniently from TornadoFX 1.7.1:

```
fragment.openModal(resizable = false)
```

It is already committed, so you can play with it in `TornadoFX 1.7.1-SNAPSHOT` if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it (Edvin can tell you when he answers), but you can just use

```
fragment.openModal()
fragment.modalStage?.isResizable = false
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I originally had but I also wasn't sure if it was the best way either